# Dell server - Redfish power metrics

Tags: dell, drac, redfish

Im having a hard time with a single Dell r620 server, which is acting a bit weird when it comes to the redfish api.

We have 10+ of the exact same r620, with same configuration, same bios/idrac/controller, where redfish power metrics is working fine, but a single server is acting out.

The problem is that powermetrics isn't updated, so when we call the url:
https://10.10.10.10/redfish/v1/Chassis/System.Embedded.1/Power

Then normally there would be an object with ex.

```
PowerMetrics": {
        "AverageConsumedWatts": 243,
        "IntervalInMin": 60,
        "MaxConsumedWatts": 401,
        "MinConsumedWatts": 224
      },
```

But this single server keeps reporting:

```
PowerMetrics": {
        "AverageConsumedWatts": 0,
        "IntervalInMin": 1,
        "MaxConsumedWatts": 0,
        "MinConsumedWatts": 0
      },
```

The powersupply setup is the same, full redundant, both connected and we can see the history of power usage in the Idrac interface just fine.

Anyone got some knowledge they want to share?

Comment: Compare the settings between the hosts. If you can't find a difference, I'd reset the iDRAC to default settings and configure it again. If it still doesn't work, open a support case with Dell.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The Exactly same thinking, reset and reconfigure, else its a Case for dell and not for ServerFault :)